# Finding a set of vectors that is not a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I am asked to find a set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that if $y$ is in the set, then $b\cdot y$ is in the set for every real number $b$. However, I am told that this set cannot be a vector space.

The set would not be a vector space if the zero vector weren't included. However, given that $b$ can be any real number, including $0$, this cannot be the case. How else can a set of vectors that matches this condition not be a vector space?

Comment: Hint. Consider a union of lines passing through the origin.

Comment: Notation-wise, I would avoid writing "$b \cdot y$" here, because it suggests a dot product. Writing $by$ is better, and if you want to make this even more clear, you could bold the vectors: "if $\mathbf y$ is in the set, then $b\mathbf y$ is in the set for every real number $b$".

Answer (score 8):

> How else can a set of vectors that matches this condition not be a vector space?

Recall that there is another condition: besides being non-empty (or containing the zero vector) and being closed under scalar multiplication, it also needs to be closed under *addition*.

**Hint**: think of the union of the coordinate axes; i.e. the $x$- and $y$-axis.

---

Consider the set $S = X \cup Y$ with:
$$\color{blue}{X = \left\{ (a,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \;\vert\; a \in \mathbb{R} \right\}}\quad,\quad \color{red}{Y = \left\{ (0,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \;\vert\; b \in \mathbb{R} \right\}}$$
Now verify that taking any $\vec s \in S$, you have for all $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ that $\lambda\vec s \in S$.

However, take $\color{blue}{\vec x} \in X$ and $\color{red}{\vec y} \in Y$ with $\vec x \ne \vec 0$ and $\vec y \ne \vec 0$; then consider $\color{purple}{\vec x + \vec y}$.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Take the set $V:=\{v\in\mathbb{R}^2: v=(x,0), v=(0,y), x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$ Clearly if $v\in V$ then for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $\alpha v\in V$, but $v_1+v_2\notin V$ where $v_1=(x,0),v_2=(0,y)$ for any such pairs and $x\neq0, y\neq 0$.

Comment: Not only this one, you could generally choose at least two lines crossing only at zero (0,0). The only thing that you do not consider for being a vector space is being closed under addition which can not be satisfied only if the addition of two vectors does not have the same direction as the rest of your consideration.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the set $S$ formed of $x=(a,c) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such as $\left|a\right|\geq \left|c\right|$.
Then for $b \in \mathbb{R}$
$$
bx=\left(ba,bc\right)
$$
and $\left|ba\right| \geq \left|bc\right|$.

However, with $(4,1)$ and $(-3,2)$ which are both in the set
$$
(4,1)+(-3,2)=(1,3)
$$
which is not in the set so it is not a vector space.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the corresponding space created by a vector(non-zero) is equivalent to a line passing through zero. Now since your assumption does not involve being closed under addition you only need to consider at least two lines which pass through zero.

Answer (score 0):

Choose any two linearly independent vectors $v,w$. Then the set

$$\{bv\mid b\in\Bbb R\}\cup\{bw\mid b\in\Bbb R\}.$$

satisfies your condition, but is not a vector space since $v+w$ is not contained (vector spaces must contain all sums of their vectors).

Answer (score 0):

You could just take the empty set. Since it is empty it isn't a vector space, but it is vacuously closed under scalar multiplication.

Obviously this is a somewhat cheap example, but it does solve the problem as stated, and underscores that existential properties (e.g. the existence of a 0 vector) can't be derived from universally quantified implications.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be the union of the first and third quadrants (along with the $x$- and $y$-axes, let's say).  Scaling by a real number $r$ will either keep each vector in its same quadrant (if $r>0$), or send the first and third quadrants to each other (if $r<0$), or send all vectors to the origin (if $r=0$).  So $S$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

However, notice that
$$
(-2, -1) + (1, 2) = (-1, 1)
$$
which is in the second quadrant, so $S$ is not closed under vector addition.

Extra note: for an example of something closed under addition but not under scalar multiplication, take just the first quadrant.